# lexical scoping and syntax-case

Tags: scheme, r6rs

I'm trying to write a pattern matching macro. I haven't got very far but I'm already confused. My test code is as follows

```
#!r6rs

(import (for (rnrs base (6)) run expand)
        (for (rnrs syntax-case (6)) expand)
        (rnrs io simple (6)))

(define-syntax matcher
  (lambda (stx)

    (define (parse-clauses c)
      #'x)

    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ c ...)
       (with-syntax ((body (parse-clauses #'(c ...))))
         #'(lambda (x) body))))))

(write ((matcher) '(1 2 3))) (newline)
```

Executing this produces the output `(1 2 3)`.

To be honest I wrote this code in the expectation that it would fail. I thought the syntax returned from `parse-clauses` refers to an undefined symbol `x`. But it seems that `#'x` returned from `parse-clauses` does reference the parameter `x` in the lambda expression. I've no idea why.

This slight variation has me even more confused.

```
#!r6rs

(import (for (rnrs base (6)) run expand)
        (for (rnrs syntax-case (6)) expand)
        (rnrs io simple (6)))

(define-syntax matcher
  (lambda (stx)

    (define (parse-clauses c)
      (let ((x 1))
        #'x))

    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ c ...)
       (with-syntax ((body (parse-clauses #'(c ...))))
         #'(lambda (x) body))))))

(write ((matcher) '(1 2 3))) (newline)
```

This produces the error `x: identifier used out of context in: x`. This error I understand, `x` is bound locally in `parse-clauses`, but I'm using the reference outside of that scope so I get an error.

I guess what I'm saying is that the second example shows that the lexical context matters but in the first example there is no lexical binding for `x` so how come it ends up referring to an unrelated binding?

I hope that's not too confused, any explanations welcome.

I'm using Racket 5.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` refers to the lambda argument because they're both introduced by the same macro expansion step -- the macro system only distinguishes identifiers introduced by different steps (if this macro expands into another macro that introduces another `x`, it will be a different one).

I think the second error is because `x` is bound as a compile-time variable (`parse-clauses` is a compile-time function) and it somehow interferes with the `x` in the lambda.